# Traefik forward-auth middleware for OpenID Connect

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-authentication

Traefik includes a [forward-auth middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/), but there is also an OIDC-specific middleware in Traefik Enterprise Edition
https://traefik.io/glossary/openid-connect-everything-you-need-to-know/

Is it possible to achieve OIDC auth with just the free forward-auth middleware in Traefik proxy? I want to secure an example service using Keycloak on Rancher Kubernetes. The forward-auth documentation isn't clear as to what the auth server can be.

Also, this GitHub project seemingly supports OIDC,
https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth but I am a little confused with the similar names. Is it the same or different from Traefik's forward-auth? Can I use this in a production setup?

- UPDATE 1: I think the way to go is to use Traefik forward auth to forward the auth request to either gogatekeeper or oauth2-proxy. These proxies work with OIDC providers in the backend and return 2XX or 4XX codes depending on the authentication result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, it's possible to achieve the OIDC auth with the forward-auth middleware but you need also an external service like https://github.com/thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth.

I'm still working on it to create a production ready service, i found this interesting project that do the work https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/ instead of thomseddon container.

I suggest this example project, made on top of docker, it explain well the behavior of the system https://github.com/BlackBeltTechnology/traefik-keycloak-sso-reverse-proxy

There is also this well documented site https://geek-cookbook.funkypenguin.co.nz/docker-swarm/traefik-forward-auth/keycloak/

Comment: Thanks, I actually got it working with oauth2-proxy and nginx ingress controller already.